# How to write horizontal label properly in confusion matrix?

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I am using the following code snippet for plotting confusion matrix using sklearn lib.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,ConfusionMatrixDisplay   
cm=confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred,normalize='true')
        
disp=ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,display_labels=['anger','bordome','disgust','fear', 'happiness','sadness' ,'neutral'])
```

and the result is given below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7jds.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in your code
`disp.plot(xticks_rotation = 'vertical')`

By default, it is displayed horizontally but this behavior can be changed.

You can find more details in the official documentation
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay